# remove and replace img once it has loaded

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to remove an element from the DOM, process it, and then reinsert it in exactly the same place once it has loaded. 
For instance, if I have an image, how would I hide it, re-size it with jQuery, and then make it visible in a way such that it would appear to load as my newly specified size? Obviously this is possible with CSS, however if the size that I'm trying to re-size the image to is RELATIVE to the size of other elements, then Javascript can actually be useful.

In the past I've solved this problem using CSS:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

But this doesn't solve the loading issue if the jQuery is being used to processes the spatial dimensions of the object.

Specifically I want to know how to reinsert an element in the SAME PLACE as it was before (in relation to the DOM). jQuery's append method only attaches the element to the end of its parent element.

Comment: And do you have any specific code for us to work with? All these things are possible, yes, but without more to go on (what do you want to *do* with this element/node once it's removed from the DOM) it's difficult to help.

Comment: It's either visibility:hidden or display:none

Comment: There's no reason to remove the image from the DOM if all you're doing is changing its height/width attributes.

Comment: one question.

REALLY! you did that with visibility:hidden?
with visibility how you can perform what you are asking in question?
wondering and want to know about it.

Comment: kind of messy code but I use visibility hidden to make the images appear to blur-in, or blur load here: http://ghghgh.us/tmp/im_working_example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the "specifically i want to know" part:
You can use [`Node.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) to place an element in the correct position. (Note that jQuery is not necessary for this operation).
This of course means, you have to know where it was (after which element), for which you can play with `Node.previousSibling`.